# I'm trying to make a button turn the LED on and off, but it just stays off instead

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I started with code to make an LED turn on while the button is pressed. That worked. 
But then I tried to tweek it so that the button would act like on 'on-off' swtich, where you only press it once to switch between states.

The led works with the older code (below) so I don't think its a problem with wiring.
FYI i skipped the setup function, its the same as when I made it blink.

```
// constants won't change. They're used here to
// set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin = 2;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int ledPin =  13;      // the number of the LED pin

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int switcher = 0;

void loop() {
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
  // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    if (switcher = 0) {
      switcher = 1;
      delay(500);
    }
    else if (switcher = 1) {
      switcher = 0;
      delay(500);
    }
  }
  if (switcher == 1) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
  /*
  else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
  */

}
```

Comment: check this example https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StateChangeDetection

Comment: Make sure you use `==` operators in your `if` conditions instead of the assignment operator `=`. Non-Boolean expressions are always true in this language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Delay` is only used if you want the whole system to stop. It is also used for learning purposes in the beginning of an Arduino career. In a real application you'll use a delay library or use timing. If you use delay in an application then you can't read the button `HIGH` event, that's means the button can only be read in the 501ms exactly after 500ms of delay, you'll have an 1ms window or less, that is nearly impossible for a human to time. Anyway you should look in to the "[Blink Without Delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay)" example from Arduino.

Also you must use a pull up resistor for buttons or declare a `INPUT_PULLUP` for the `pinMode` in the setup, to avoid bouncing, see example below.

### This is how you solve the code:

```
// defined constants in Arduino don’t take up any program memory space on the chip.
#define buttonPin 2;
#define ledPin 13;

// bytes are half the size of int's, but restricted to a max value of 255
byte value;
byte oldValue = 0;
byte state = 0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(buttonPin , INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  value = digitalRead(buttonPin );
  if(value && !oldValue) // same as if(button == high && oldValue == low)
  {
    //we have a new button press
    if(state == 0) // if the state is off, turn it on
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      state = 1;
    }
    else // if the state is on, turn it off
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      state = 0;
    }
    oldValue = 1;
  }
  else if(!value && oldValue) // same as if(button == low && oldValue == high)
  {
    // the button was released
    oldValue = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! You mentioned that you would have to press the button at exactly the 501ms, but I thought that I added a delay only for AFTER you press it. I added the delay so that it wouldn't loop through more than once and give a reading of the button being on 'HIGH'

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StateChangeDetection

```
/*
  State change detection (edge detection)

  Often, you don't need to know the state of a digital input all the time, but
  you just need to know when the input changes from one state to another.
  For example, you want to know when a button goes from OFF to ON. This is called
  state change detection, or edge detection.

  This example shows how to detect when a button or button changes from off to on
  and on to off.

  The circuit:
  - pushbutton attached to pin 2 from +5V
  - 10 kilohm resistor attached to pin 2 from ground
  - LED attached from pin 13 to ground (or use the built-in LED on most
    Arduino boards)

  created  27 Sep 2005
  modified 30 Aug 2011
  by Tom Igoe

  This example code is in the public domain.

  http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ButtonStateChange
*/

// this constant won't change:
const int  buttonPin = 2;    // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to
const int ledPin = 13;       // the pin that the LED is attached to

// Variables will change:
int buttonPushCounter = 0;   // counter for the number of button presses
int buttonState = 0;         // current state of the button
int lastButtonState = 0;     // previous state of the button

void setup() {
  // initialize the button pin as a input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  // initialize the LED as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() {
  // read the pushbutton input pin:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // compare the buttonState to its previous state
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    // if the state has changed, increment the counter
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
      // if the current state is HIGH then the button went from off to on:
      buttonPushCounter++;
      Serial.println("on");
      Serial.print("number of button pushes: ");
      Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
    } else {
      // if the current state is LOW then the button went from on to off:
      Serial.println("off");
    }
    // Delay a little bit to avoid bouncing
    delay(50);
  }
  // save the current state as the last state, for next time through the loop
  lastButtonState = buttonState;


  // turns on the LED every two button pushes by checking the modulo of the
  // button push counter. the modulo function gives you the remainder of the
  // division of two numbers:
  if (buttonPushCounter % 2 == 0) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }

}
```

Comment: As said in the example "// Delay a little bit to avoid bouncing" `Delay(50)`. That is adding a bug into the system and not how you do electrical engineering for buttons. You should use a pull-up resistor or declare it in code. See my example. I know this is copied from Arduino but it's merely used for teaching purposes and not applicable in real life.

Answer (score 1):

Using this Code, When you press the Push Button Led will be ON and when you again press the Push Button Led will be OFF always state changes when you press the button.

```
const int buttonPin = 2;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int ledPin =  13;      // the number of the LED pin

int switchState = 0; // actual read value from pin4
int oldSwitchState = 0; // last read value from pin4
int lightsOn = 0; // is the switch on = 1 or off = 0


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);   // declare LED as output
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT); // declare push button as input
}

void loop() {

  switchState = digitalRead(buttonPin); // read the pushButton State

  if (switchState != oldSwitchState) // catch change
  {
    oldSwitchState = switchState;
    if (switchState == HIGH)
    {
      // toggle
      lightsOn = !lightsOn; // invert the values
    }
  }

  if (lightsOn)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // set the LED on
    Serial.println("LED Turned ON");
  } else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // set the LED off
    Serial.println("LED Turned Off");
  }
}
```